# Render light or texture problem

Tags: rendering, animation

The graphics rendering image shows a problem that also exists in the viewport shading with realtime rendering. The grass seems to be reflected on the wall. Depends on what? The last picture shows the full texture of the wall. The bugs disappear with an animation. Sorry but I don't attach the blender file because it's too heavy. I use cycle. Thank you

https://imgbox.com/peKiPfJX
https://imgbox.com/1liaU8Jp
[image: image host]

https://imgbox.com/L63bt2y3
https://imgbox.com/imE1bNxr

[image: image host] [image: image host]

[image: image host]
https://imgbox.com/hEfzNwCn

Comment: Next step (unless you want to include your file with packed data via [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/))... Include a screen cap that shows your Shaders for the wall.  I only see shaders for your World background.

Comment: Please help me! I don't understand where the problem is and I don't know how to attach the file because it weighs too much! The surface has the normal ok and I cleaned from dirt with Merge. Are the problem the textures?

Comment: SaveAs "reduced.blend", select grass wall and overpass, select-Inverse, delete, File_ExternalData_Pack, save - should give you a smaller file that will be accepted, and sufficient for us to work with.